# Kentico 12 MVC - Add a Forms selector inside a widget

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-mvc

How do I add a Forms widget inside another widget? I tried using FormZone() within the widget but nothing shows up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to render a Forms widget inside another widget in Kentico 12 MVC.

You will need to upgrade to Kentico Xperience 13 for this functionality - see https://docs.xperience.io/developing-websites/page-builder-development/rendering-widgets-in-code#Renderingwidgetsincode-Renderingwidgets

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can render a Form inside a Widget in Kentico 12, however it is not officially supported and requires a bit of custom development.

The key is to use `IFormProvider` and `IFormComponentVisibilityEvaluator` to get all the Form info so that you can render it manually (in a Controller):

```cs
var formInfo = BizFormInfoProvider
    .GetBizFormInfo(formName, SiteContext.CurrentSiteName);

string className = DataClassInfoProvider
    .GetClassName(formInfo.FormClassID);

var existingBizFormItem = className is null
    ? null
    : BizFormItemProvider
        .GetItems(className)?.GetExistingItemForContact(
           formInfo, contactContext.ContactGuid);

var formComponents = formProvider
    .GetFormComponents(formInfo)
    .GetDisplayedComponents(
      ContactManagementContext.CurrentContact, 
      formInfo, existingBizFormItem, visibilityEvaluator);

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
    StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml
};

var formConfiguration = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FormBuilderConfiguration>(
    formInfo.FormBuilderLayout, settings);

var prefix = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = prefix;

return new FormWidgetViewModel
{
    DisplayValidationErrors = true,
    FormComponents = formComponents.ToList(),
    FormConfiguration = formConfiguration,
    FormName = formName,
    FormPrefix = prefix,
    IsFormSubmittable = true,
    SiteForms = new List<SelectListItem>(),
    SubmitButtonImage = formInfo.FormSubmitButtonImage,
    SubmitButtonText = string.IsNullOrEmpty(formInfo.FormSubmitButtonText) 
      ? ResHelper.GetString("general.submit")
      : ResHelper.LocalizeString(formInfo.FormSubmitButtonText)
};
```

Then you would render the Form Model as an HTML Form using Kentico's Form rendering APIs:

```html
<!-- ~/Views/Form/Form.cshtml -->

@using Kentico.Forms.Web.Mvc;
@using Kentico.Forms.Web.Mvc.Widgets;
@using Kentico.Forms.Web.Mvc.Widgets.Internal

@model FormWidgetViewModel

@{
    var config = FormWidgetRenderingConfiguration.Default;

    // @Html.Kentico().FormSubmitButton(Model) requires 
    // this ViewData value to be populated. Normally it
    // executes as part of the Widget rendering, but since
    // we aren't rendering a Widget, we have to do it manually

    ViewData.AddFormWidgetRenderingConfiguration(config);
}

@using (Html.Kentico().BeginForm(Model))
{
    @Html.Kentico().FormFields(Model)

    @Html.Kentico().FormSubmitButton(Model)
}
```

You can read about the full configuration and setup in my blog post [Kentico EMS: MVC Widget Experiments Part 3 - Rendering Form Builder Forms Without Widgets](https://dev.to/seangwright/kentico-ems-mvc-widget-experiments-part-3-rendering-form-builder-forms-without-widgets-58k8)